# Cannot find git while installing foundation

Tags: ruby, git, zurb-foundation

I am new to ZURB Foundation and trying to install it through Ruby CLI.
I have successfully installed ZURB Foundation and now I want to create a new project with this command:

```
foundation new myFound
```

It gives me an error saying:

> Can't find Git.

I have installed Git on my system but still have this error. I run on Windows. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to check this option during the installation to add Git on `PATH`:

> Use Git from the Windows Command Promt

Picture

[image]

If you didn't do it you can reinstall the Git or add it on the `PATH` manually (I assume that your Git's installation folder is `C:\Program Files (x86)\Git` - if doesn't, change it to yours).

**Command line approach**

```
set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin
```

**Graphical approach**

- Select Computer from the Start menu
- Choose System Properties from the context menu
- Click Advanced system settings > Advanced tab
- Click on Environment Variables
- Select Path in the section System Variables and edit it
- add `;C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin` at the end and save it